# What do you say for opening a door rapidly?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for the correct idiom when someone opens a door quickly. Different translations I found say "to tear open" but I have the feeling that "tear open" rather means something like opening the packaging of something and not opening a door.

Comment: The problem is the person opening the door. He opened the door quickly/slowly. There is no idiom, though. tear open is wrong. He pushed the door open brusquely/roughly/fast.

Comment: Try "flung open the door": https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fling-a-door-open

Comment: @Juhasz I think you can fling open a door if you are on the side away from which it opens. From the other side (so that the door opens towards you) you could say, tug, yank, or perhaps even tear.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, while what you say makes sense, I don't think I use the phrase that sensibly.  That is, I would probably be OK with "fling" from either side of the door.

Comment: You could also try **ripped** open

Comment: I am looking for when you push the door to the inside. So it looks like "fling" or "throw" (as in the answer) are the best. But that's a good point that you can of course rip/yank it open from the other side. I guess one may even be able to throw it open from the other side, when it still hits the wall afterward?

Answer (score 2):

You can [*fling*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fling) the door open.

> He walked purposefully straight toward Eddie Willers, **he flung the glass door open** and, from the threshold, in the sight and hearing of the room, he screamed "Where is she?"

You can [*throw*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/throw) the door open.

> She ran through the dark anteroom, **she threw the door open** and looked out.

It depends on the context, but either of them can imply force, speed, sudden movement.

There are a few mentions of *tearing the door open*, but most of them are used in the sense of breaking it, [ripping it off](https://i.gifer.com/origin/15/15fe2bd87975719b7db8a06fa259ff23_w200.gif), getting past it.

[image]